Dropdown with cell specific values on InputBox using App Script
I'm currently working on a project in Google Sheets and I'm attempting to make a InputBox with a Dropdown menu. The dropdown options should be from specific cells (A:A), I managed to create the InputBox and the dropdown using HTML and Google Apps Script, but the Dropdown is empty.
Empty dropdown
HTML Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="opcoes" onchange="selecionarOpcao()">
    </select>
    <script>
      function preencherMenuSuspenso() {
        var opcoes = <?= JSON.stringify(opcoes) ?>;

        var select = document.getElementById('opcoes');

        select.innerHTML = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++) {
          var option = document.createElement('option'); 
          option.value = opcoes[i]; 
          option.text = opcoes[i];
          select.appendChild(option);
        }
      }

      function selecionarOpcao() {
        var opcaoSelecionada = document.getElementById('opcoes').value;
        google.script.run.onOpcaoSelecionada(opcaoSelecionada);
        google.script.host.close();
      }

      window.onload = preencherMenuSuspenso;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

GS Code:
function mostrarInputBoxComMenuSuspenso() {
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var intervalo = planilha.getSheetByName('BD').getRange('A1:A50');
  var valores = intervalo.getValues();
  
  var opcoes = valores.map(function(valor) {
    return valor[0];
  });

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MenuSuspenso')
      .setWidth(300)
      .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Selecione uma opção');

  function onOpcaoSelecionada(opcaoSelecionada) {
    if (opcaoSelecionada) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Opção selecionada: ' + opcaoSelecionada);
    }
  }
}

How can i make my options from A:A appear on the dropdown?

You are using snippets but you never created a template that could be evaluated- Templated Html
